# How to find un_ install user in android app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I can identify which gcm id was install in my android app,but i cant identify who un_install in my android app. so i want know about that user with gcm id. please help me friends.If anyone knows share with me.

Thanks friends.

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check that directly. But you check the error response from GCM, if you get for example `Unregistered Device` then all you have to do is to remove that token from your database.

See more details [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#message-with-payload--data-message) and [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes).